# matplotlib Error: No module named matplotlib even though it is installed

Tags: 12.04, python3, matplotlib

I have been through the process of installing matplotlib on my Ubuntu 12.04 computer. However, when I try to run a test program, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../py33/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I am trying a sample program from matplotlib's website (basic_example). I just don't understand why it says there is not module matplotlib, even though I have definitely installed it (using `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib`, and have done `sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib;` I also tried `pip install matplotlib`, as I was told to do that, after installing Python itself, if I wanted to install other binaries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are using `python3`. So in order to run your script you need either to use python2.x or to make sure you have `matplotlib v1.2` or higher. This is because `matplotlib` does not support python3 before v1.2.

I am using `matplotlib v1.1` with `python2.7` and I have no problem. I tried to do a simple `import matplotlib` with `python3` and it gives the same error as you.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to install Matplotlib for Python 3 through the APT package manager, you need the package `python3-matplotlib`:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

If you want to install it with Pip for Python 3, you need to use `pip3`:

```
sudo pip3 install matplotlib
```

Answer (score 2):

**Cite:**

> ...even though I have definitely installed it (`using sudo apt-get install`
>   `python-matplotlib`, and have done `sudo apt-get build-dep`
>   `python-matplotlib`; I also tried `pip install matplotlib`, as I was told
>   to do that, after installing Python itself, if I wanted to install
>   other binaries).

**Possible solution:**

Taken from the official web page 
(https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html ),
try this:

> python -mpip install -U pip
>
> python -mpip install -U matplotlib

(first line installs pip, a manager installer for libraries,
second line install matplotlib itself).

**Commentaries:**

I had same problem at my Ubuntu 16.04, this works very well for that version.

Best regards,