# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Tags: jupyter, matplotlib

I cannot draw a plot in a jupyter notebook. It says: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib' " even though I have installed the matplotlib.

I have Ubuntu 18.04 as OS.

(By the way, I noticed that I have several python versions in my /usr/lib like, python2.7, python3 ; 3.6; 3.7 .)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib Error: No module named matplotlib even though it is installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427708/matplotlib-error-no-module-named-matplotlib-even-though-it-is-installed)

Answer (score 0):

try to install matplotlib for python3

e.g.:

```
sudo pip3 install matplotlib
```